# Google play - Ending beta test period

Tags: android, google-play, google-plus, beta-testing

Is it possible to end beta testing,
without asking the beta-testers to enter the designated beta testing page,
and clicking "leave test"?

will the following options work?

1. deleting the beta testers google+ community
2. removing the community from google play list of testers

My goal is that the beta testers will get an auto update to the newer version,
that will be uploaded to the production channel.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your users will automatically receive the latest version AVAILABLE* for them, so all you need to do is upload your application to *Production* and make sure that `versionCode` in *Production* is higher that in *Beta*.

*all versions from *Production* are avalible for all users; by assignig users to Google Group you are making versions from *Beta* avalible for this group, so they will receive newest version from both channels.